# how to post raw json array to server in retrofit

Tags: android, json, retrofit

every time i run this function onfaliure calls [image: image of postman when i post data through post man]
**json array**

```
{"ORDER":[{"ORDER_DATE":"2020-09-08 01:28:11 PM","CUSTOMER_ID":"umersaleem_03334033313","PRODUCT_ID":"","QUANTITY":1,"DEAL_ID":"1","ORDER_TOTAL":"600.0"}
```

**interface**

```
@POST("/restaro/index.php/Home/insert_order_info")
Call<CheckloginModel> insertOrder(@Body JSONObject j);
```

**function**

```
   retrofitApiInterface.insertOrder(orders)
            .enqueue(new Callback<CheckloginModel>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<CheckloginModel> call, Response<CheckloginModel> response) {

                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<CheckloginModel> call, Throwable t) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Poor internet connection or device is Off ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                  

                }
            });
}
```

**api response**
this the response when the data is inserted through postman

```
{
    "status": 1,
    "message": "new order added "
}
```

when i send it on postman the data is inserting need help thanks in advance

Comment: **Request Model**
model of response of api
  ```@Expose
  @SerializedName("status")
  int status;

  @Expose
  @SerializedName("message")
  String message;

  }```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
@POST("/restaro/index.php/Home/insert_order_info")
Call< CheckloginModel> insertOrder(@Body RequestBody body);
```

request body send with your json and send this request body to api.

```
 JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject();
            try {
                jsonObject.put("value",  "value");
                

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            RequestBody requestBody=RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"),jsonObject.toString());
```

Comment: if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                            CheckloginModel model = response.body();
                         else {
                             
                            Log.e("TAG", "no successfull");
                        }
                    }

Comment: now the else clause is executing and data is not inserted

Answer (score -1):

**I will only this line and pass requestbody Retrofit call and works for me**

```
 RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8"), jsonObject1.toString());
                        Call<CheckOutResponse> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getApi().postOrder(requestBody);
                        call.enqueue(new Callback<CheckOutResponse>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(Call<CheckOutResponse> call, Response<CheckOutResponse> response) {
                                CheckOutResponse checkOutResponse = response.body();


 @Override
                            public void onFailure(Call<CheckOutResponse> call, Throwable t) {

                            }
                        });
```

**Webservice class**

```
@POST("yourAPiCall")
Call<CheckOutResponse> postOrder(@Body RequestBody requestBody);
```